# How can i apply Absorption law in this expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have this expression:

A + A * B * C'

I know that i can use the Absorption law in this and the answer is A, but how can i apply that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write it as :

> $A + (A * (B * C'))$.

Now you can apply [Absorption Law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsorptionLaw.html).

Answer (score 2):

Absorption Law: A + AB = A
in your example let D = BC'
A + AD = A

This works because no matter what A is multiplied by, the result of the expression will always be A.  This is because if what A is ANDed with is 0 then the result is 0 OR A which is A.  However if what A is ANDed with is a 1 then your get A Or A which is again A.

Comment: Please consider rewording your answer to make it more clear and precise, as well as employing LaTeX formatting because as of now, I can't really read it.